# YouTube: Is it possible to get the timestamp of a video based on searching its Auto CC?

Tags: youtube, closed-captions

For example, say there's a 3 hour City Council meeting, and they do not document the time stamps for each topic in the description of the video. But I know somewhere in there they talk about a new excise tax.

Is there a way that I can search "excise tax" within the auto-generated closed captioning, which would return timestamps of this phrase being spoken?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. If CC is available on the video, then on PC you can click the ellipses next to the share button on the video, click "Open Transcript", and then CTRL+F seems to work normally.

Clicking on the caption in this window will take you to the timestamp.